# How to blink table row based on condition using jquery or php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i want to add blink effect to specific table row based on value contain in row is equal to value in php variable. for example if php variable value is 'ABC' then blink table row containing text 'ABC', dynamically.. i have added css code in head for blink.. but may be php variable is not passing in jquery in below code..how to add blink effect to complete row? any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance..

```
<html>
<head>
<title> Blink Row </title>

<style>
.blink {
        color: #FF0000;
        animation: blinker 1s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes blinker {
        50% {
        opacity: 0;
        }
}
</style>


</head>

<?php

$varName = 'ABC';


echo '
    <table id="tb_id" class="table table-striped">
<thead>
    <tr bgcolor="#E6E6FA">
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th>Address</th>        
    </tr>
</thead>';

foreach( $rows as $row ){

echo "
    <tr>
        <td class='grn'>{$row[0]}</td>
        <td>{$row[1]}</td>
    <td>{$row[2]}</td>
    </tr>";
    }
    echo '
    </table>';


?>

<script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#tb_id td.grn').each(function(){
        var empName = '<?php echo $varName; ?>';
                if ($(this).text() == empName) {
                $(this).css('background-color','#080');
                }
        });
});
</script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logic works, you just need to add the `blink` class to the parent `tr` of each matching `td`, which can be achieved using `.closest()` and `addClass()`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var empName = 'abc';

  $('#tb_id td.grn').each(function() {
    if ($(this).text() == empName) {
      $(this).css('background-color', '#080').closest('tr').addClass('blink');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.blink {
  color: #FF0000;
  animation: blinker 1s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes blinker {
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tb_id" class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr bgcolor="#E6E6FA">
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Address</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class='grn'>abc</td>
      <td>Email0</td>
      <td>Address0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class='grn'>def</td>
      <td>Email1</td>
      <td>Address1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class='grn'>abc</td>
      <td>Email2</td>
      <td>Address2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

However it's worth noting that this can be simplified using the `:contains` selector:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var empName = 'abc';

  $('#tb_id td.grn:contains("' + empName + '")').closest('tr').addClass('blink');
});
```

```css
.blink {
  color: #FF0000;
  animation: blinker 1s linear infinite;
}

.blink>td:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: #080;
}

@keyframes blinker {
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tb_id" class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr bgcolor="#E6E6FA">
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Address</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class='grn'>abc</td>
      <td>Email0</td>
      <td>Address0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class='grn'>def</td>
      <td>Email1</td>
      <td>Address1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class='grn'>abc</td>
      <td>Email2</td>
      <td>Address2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Your code already worked in that regard. I only hard coded the value in the example as PHP is not interpreted in snippets

Comment: with hard coded value its working.. but after passing php variable its not working...

Comment: please edit using without hard coded value and pass variable value.. how to pass it

Comment: thank you ..finally it works .. when i use json_encode.. :)